# Plotly: How To Show State Lines on Choropleth Map

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I have a choropleth map of the United States, but the border lines separating each state is white against a white background. How do I customize this map to show a black border line instead?

[USA Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GFh3.png)

Here are my codes:

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs,init_notebook_mode,plot,iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

data = dict(type = 'choropleth',
            locations = ['AZ','CA','NY'],
            locationmode = 'USA-states',
            colorscale = 'Jet',
            text = ['Arizon','California','New York'],
            z = [1.0,2.0,3.0],
            colorbar = {'title':'Colorbar Title Goes Here!'})

layout = dict(geo={'scope':'usa'})

choromap = go.Figure(data = [data],layout=layout)

iplot(choromap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it might be too late for you, but I think I am doing the same Udemy course...

so, after defining 'choromap' as a go.Figure object, you can modify its properties like this:

```
choromap.update_geos(visible=True,
                 showsubunits=True, subunitcolor='black')
```

There are a lot of properties to change color to. You can call builtin help for the list, ot even just misspell a property and the list will be in the stack trace.